# log4net Configuration for console app

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, application-start

can anyone suggest how to configure the log4net for an console app?

Or at least how/where to catch the `Application_Start` event? (It seams that some calls are required at this moment)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to configure it before the first logger is instantiated.

To do so:

- Your main class (Program.cs) should not have a logger
- The main method should not reference any classes that have a logger.
- You can then configure log4net in the main method.

Alternatively you can use a wrapper class to instantiate loggers, that ensures log4net is configured before creating a logger, e.g.:

```
static class Log4NetHelper
{
    private static bool _isConfigured;

    static void EnsureConfigured()
    {
        if (!_isConfigured)
        {
            ... configure log4net here ...
            _isConfigured = true;
        }
    }

    public static ILog GetLogger(string name)
    {
        EnsureConfigured();
        log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(name);
        return logger;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Try writing

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

in `AssemblyInfo.cs`

That's it!

Comment: What is this supposed to do ? I doesn't seem to help anything in my case.

Comment: It is supposed to 1) tell log4net to configure itself using the default settings (app.config) 2) cause log4net to auto-reload it's configuration when the underlying file that contains the log4net entry changes.

Comment: @Tomas you also need to add the log4net config to the app.config file